# AJAX to fetch, get same funcionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ajax, frontend

i want to know how can i get the same funcionality from ajax jquery to fetch javascript

this is my ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data, //FormData
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error(e) {
        console.log(e.responseJSON.message); //<---this is what i want in my fetch :)"this is my error text"
    }
});
```

and there my fetch

```
options = {
            method: "POST",
            body: data // FormData
        }
const response = await fetch(url, options);
if(!response.ok){
     return response.statusText;//always "internal server error" i need my custom msg for user ;(
}
```

my backend in laravel

```
abort(500, "this is my error text");
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `response.text()` to get the actual response body

```
options = {
        method: "POST",
        body: data // FormData
}
const response = await fetch(url, options);
if(!response.ok){
    return response.text();
}
```

Comment: it throw me a html body, is not the same as jquery response

Comment: How are you getting html body if your backend if just `abort(500, "this is my error text");`?  What is your backend actually returning?

Comment: `<html>
<body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <div class="code">
                500            </div>

            <div class="message" style="padding: 10px;">
                Server Error            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`
with Jquery ajax it give me the message that i put in abort function